# Speed up Excel PowerShell modification to file

Tags: excel, powershell, automation, comparison

I have a process which will look for a value in a cell and compare it with an array, then it will replace that value with the corresponding value from the second array.

This script is working, but I'm looking into how to tune it and make it fast.

```
$ColorCodes = "001", "002", "003"
$FAColors = "Blue", "Red", "White"
$XLSXDoc = "c:\Users\w0517\Desktop\ColorCodes.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($XLSXDoc)
$Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetName)
$WriteData = $Excel.WorkSheets.Item($SheetName)
$RowCount = ($Sheet.usedRange.rows).count
write-host The Excel Sheet Has $RowCount Rows
For ($J=2; $J -le $RowCount; $J++)
    {
       $MainColor = $Sheet.Cells.Item("$J",2).Text
       $ArrayIndex = [array]::IndexOf($FAColors, $MainColor)
       $WriteData.Cells.Item("$J",2) = $ColorCodes[$ArrayIndex] 

    }
$Excel.Visible = $true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the builtin [`Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method on the entire column will be a lot faster than changing each cell individually:

```psh
$colors = @{
  'Blue'  = "'001"
  'Red'   = "'002"
  'White' = "'003"
}

$wbName = 'C:\Users\w0517\Desktop\ColorCodes.xlsx'
$wsName = 'Sheet1'

$xl = New-Object -COM 'Excel.Application'
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($wbName)
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item($wsName)

$colors.Keys | % {
  $ws.Cells.Item(1,2).EntireColumn.Replace($_, $colors[$_])
}

$xl.Visible = $true
```

Comment: will try and get back to you

Comment: why the value will be inserted as int, although the cell format type is text , it shows 2 instead of 002

Comment: @AhmedAl-Haffar Prefix the values with a single quote to prevent that.